# Omitted で or があって in set phrase used in tag この指とまれ; apparently may/can be in 錠剤腐る脳

Tags: grammar, etymology, particle-で, omission

The phrase この指とまれ is interpreted as a phrase to stop the tagger and gather runners near the person who said the phrase. I searched it up and apparently it comes from the tradition of 指切り (promising; literally to chop one's finger off). So, is this just simple omission and you can interpret what's between この指 and とまれ and で/があって is just what you can make out from it? Or is it merely a set phrase? Or, can you (maybe also?) omit で (of course not in regular sentences) in very specific poetic situations or will it just be a case of simple omission and implication (but この指とまれ has no spacing, maybe because it's in a panic but I haven't researched 鬼ごっこ) Also, a translator told me that they interpreted 錠剤腐る脳(に投与, お礼) as a phrase omitting で in  錠剤腐る (I thought it was "My brain that pills wore out on")

Comment: Although this question has an accepted answer, I'm very confused by its wording. For me この指とまれ doesn't relate to 指切り at all. It's a phrase used by kids when asking who wants to join a play（○○する人この指とまれ）, and isn't a phrase heard in 鬼ごっこ either. I really fail to understand the 錠剤腐る脳(に投与，お礼) part, too.

Comment: I misunderstood https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1231316397

Answer (score 2, accepted):

この指とまれ and 指切り are set phrases. They are practically never used in the version with particles, but they should be この指**に**とまれ and 指**を**切る (in nominal form, を must be omitted). These are simply understood from the valency of the verbs とまる and 切る.

As for 錠剤腐る脳に投与, because it is unusual, one can never know what particle is omitted for sure.

One way to guess: 脳が腐る seems to make sense, so if anything it is by 錠剤で, whence it is 錠剤**で**腐る脳 = brain that get rotten by pills. But note で is generally not omittable. As such, this guess is, grammatically speaking, a wrong guess. It is only plausible by meaning.

Another way: the most natural phrase that is missing in 腐る is the subject, so 錠剤**が**腐る脳 = brain where pills decay, which seems to make even less sense. This is a grammatical guess but semantically less likely.　(E.g. トリュフ香るポテトチップス is *crisps with truffle flagrance* - it is トリュフ**が**香る...)

Comment: Thank you! If there was anything else that can be elaborated on I would appreciate it if it was! I knew に could have that use but it didn't come to my mind.